# Capturar apenas linha

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou com uma tabela criada em array, e o botão modal abre uma tabela para seleção de unidades de peso / medida, mas quando a seleção é capturada preenche a tabela toda como na foto abaixo. Como faço para preencher somente a linha ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura da tabela aberta ao clicar no modal

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>  Unidade </th>
           <th>  Descrição </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
       include ("conn.php");

       $result = "SELECT * FROM cadunid ORDER BY descricao";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
           echo "<tr class='btn-default'>";
               echo "<td class='get-value'>". $row['codigo'] ."</td>";
               echo "<td class='get-value-codigo'>". $row['descricao'] ."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }                      
   ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

estrutura da tabela mostrada na imagem acima

```
<table class="table table-bordered"><!-- Iniciando a Tabela -->
    <thead>
       <tr><!-- Início dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
         <th><button type="button" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Unidade >>                 </button></th>
         <th>Preço Custo</th>
         <th>Preço Venda</th>
         <th>Peso Bruto</th>
         <th>Peso Liquido</th>
         <th>Qtd. Emb.</th>
       </tr><!-- Fim dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
    </thead>

    <tbody id='prprod'><!-- Início do Corpo da tabela / Quantidade de linhas e colunas -->
    <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar ?>        
    <tr>                                                   
      <input type="hidden" maxlength="6"  name="recnum[]" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;">
      <td><input type='text' name="unidad[]" class="unidade-input" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;">                                                               
      <td><input type="text" maxlength=""  name="preco_custo[]" placeholder="" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
      <td><input type="text" maxlength=""  name="preco_venda[]" placeholder="" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
      <td><input type="text" maxlength=""  name="peso_bruto[]" placeholder="" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
      <td><input type="text" maxlength=""  name="peso_liquido[]" placeholder="" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
      <td><input type="text" maxlength=""  name="qtde_embalagem[]" placeholder="" style="border:none; width:100%; background-color: transparent;"></td>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    </tbody><!-- Fim do Corpo da tabela / Quantidade de linhas e colunas -->

</table><!-- Finalizando a Tabela -->
```

script utilizado para capturar unidade selecionada pelo usuário

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.get-value', function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('.close').trigger('click');
    $('.unidade-input', "tr").find.val(value); /* tentei desta forma porém continua preenchendo toda tabela */
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.get-value-codigo', function() {
      var value = $(this).siblings('.get-value').text();
      $('.close').trigger('click');
      $('.unidade-input').val(value);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: tanta colocar ID's nas linhas... ai depois quando for preencher pega a tr com x ID

Comment: não tem como colocar id num loop for, teria de ser class, pois ID é único de um elemento já class poderia ser definido para todos os elementos do array, por isso está setado com class

Comment: loop for que eu saiba ele vai aumentando... usa a variavel do proprio loop como ID, mas se voce diz que n da entao n usa :D

Comment: Já tentei fazer o teste com ID, e ele não captura a seleção do usuário, já com class sim, pois class é utilizado para todos elementos percorridos no while, e id faria com que todos elementos trazidos na tabela do modal tivesse o mesmo id, ou seja, isso é impossível, trazer um while com ID ao invés de class, entende ? Meu problema é trazer apenas uma linha e não em capturar o dado

Answer (score 0):

Atenderia o seu caso se você inserisse uma linha dinamicamente cada vez que o usuário termina de preencher os dados do modal?

> Ao clicar no botão de `unidade` abrir o modal com os campos a serem
>   preenchidos, após o preenchimento dos campos utilizando o próprio javascript
>   inserir uma linha na tabela.

Assim você permite o usuário inserir quantas linhas quiser. E inicialmente sua tabela terá apenas o conteúdo do cabeçalho.

Comment: quando não der uma resposta coerente para a pergunta apenas comente @Henrique Oliveira